# htaccess removing part of url path and stay at base (at localhost)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've gone through all QA here, but I am not getting it right.

I am using wamp and my site resides in a folder named 'site'.

I am trying to redirect this

```
http://localhost/site/public/foo/bar/
```

to

```
http://localhost/site/foo/bar/
```

using these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

but it redirects to

```
http://localhost/foo/bar/
```

If I explicitly mention it in rule then it works.

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Can I write a rule without explicitly adding /site/ ?

Comment: Yes you can. Try this `RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this please?

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Imagine what you say to apache ;)  Apache should rewrite "public/*" with "/*". You're going from relative to absolute. Thats the problem.