# PHP - make url smaller but with the same functionality

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I've got a CMS which I created by myself and I have an external link, which shows the web created by the user.

The link is: [http://localhost/CMS/www/users_template/{user_name}](http://localhost/CMS/%7Buser_name%7D)

Is there any possibility to change the link and make it:

[http://localhost/CMS/{user_name}](http://localhost/CMS/%7Buser_name%7D)

but it should still show the web page without any errors?

I think I should edit my `.htaccess` file, but no idea how to do it. I have never edited the `.htaccess` file before.

Comment: How are you displaying it? Can't you just modify the string?

Comment: search about clean url

Comment: See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Demodave I am using a framework. I can't just modify it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess removing part of url path and stay at base (at localhost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760722/htaccess-removing-part-of-url-path-and-stay-at-base-at-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate.

Please view `.htaccess`: [removing part of url path and stay at base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760722/htaccess-removing-part-of-url-path-and-stay-at-base-at-localhost)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CMS/

RewriteRule ^www/users_template/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @demodave - In the future if you find a duplicate, please flag it as such.